# create two method for same url pattern with different arguments

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have scenario where one url "serachUser" may come with two different value (request parameter) userId or UserName.

so for this I have created two methods

```
public String searchUserById(@RequestParam long userID, Model model) 
public ModelAndView searchUserByName(@RequestParam String userName)
```

But i am getting  Ambiguous mapping found exception. Can Spring handle this situation?

Answer (score 254, accepted):

You can use the [`params`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--) parameter to filter by HTTP parameters. In your case it would be something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchUser", params = "userID")
public String searchUserById(@RequestParam long userID, Model model) {
  // ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/searchUser", params = "userName")
public ModelAndView searchUserByName(@RequestParam String userName) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: The other way I had handled this is to accept the parameter as a String, then call Long.parseLong() on it.  If it parses, then its the the userId, if it doesn't, assume its the username.

Comment: In case you want to know how it works when you have multiple params, you can use `params = { "storeId", "containerLabel" }`

Comment: if url mapping and all other parameters are same, is it give a deployment time exception?

Comment: But will it be possible to assign different role/function to this url to authorise?

Comment: Related: Swagger might not fully support this. I found this issue http://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1828. I use Spring Fox 2.7.0 and the Swagger UI only shows 1 method instead of 2. Apparently this can be fixed by `enableUrlTemplating(true)` and using an experimental Swagger UI: http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#springfox-rfc6570-support-strong-incubating-strong

Comment: The URL should have that userID keyword in it. Spring matched it using that.

Comment: what if I call `/searchUser?userID=abc&userName=xyz`? Which of the controller will get called?

Comment: What if the incoming request has a JSON body, which can be mapped to two types of DTO? Does Spring have some mechanism to distinguish them?

Comment: @WesternGun I'm also interested in this. Have you found something?

Comment: @QuintenScheppermans sorry, not yet. Till this moment, I think I have to pass an extra param to distinguish them. Cannot see any other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Any way incase of request param null is allowed if you don't pass any value it will be null then you can write your coad like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchUser", params = {"userID","userName"})
public String searchUserById(@RequestParam long userID,@RequestParam String 
userName, 
Model model) {    
if(userID != null){
//..
}else{
// ...
}
```