# How to map two different urls in a Controller: one url with param and the same without the param?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have two URLs to map:
The root : `http://www.website.com` : When user request the root I want to show the home page.
The root *with parameter*: `http://www.website.com?ref=xxxx` : When user requests this, I want to create a cookie and go to the root ("/").

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String doGreatThings(
    @RequestParam(value="ref", required=false) String identifier,
    ServletRequest request, 
    ServletResponse response){

        if(identifier!=null){

        }
        return "/";
    }
```

This gives me an infinite loop. Is it possible to distinguish between both mappings in the controller?

```
http://www.mywebsite.com
```

vs.

```
http://www.mywebsite.com?ref=xxxxx
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [create two method for same url pattern with different arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853035/create-two-method-for-same-url-pattern-with-different-arguments)

Answer (score 2):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853035/create-two-method-for-same-url-pattern-with-different-arguments/15853217#15853217) linked in some of the previous comments is the way to go.

You should use the `params` attribute of the `@RequestMapping` to filter by param, but note that you can also negate this filter, so map to an url that doesn't contain a param. Following should be a mapping that works for you

the mapping without the parameter note the `!` that marks the negation

```
@RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET, params="!ref")
public ModelAndView doGreatThings(
    @RequestParam(value="ref", required=false) String identifier,
    ServletRequest request, 
    ServletResponse response){
    // show home page
}
```

the mapping with the parameter

```
@RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET, params="ref")
public ModelAndView doGreatThings(
    @RequestParam(value="ref") String identifier,
    ServletRequest request, 
    ServletResponse response){
        // create the cookie
        // redirect to home page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my answer as per @kryger comment, You can use `params` attribute to filter by parameter.

Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853035/create-two-method-for-same-url-pattern-with-different-arguments/15853217#15853217) for the original answer.

Comment: This is not true, as per my answer to a nearly-identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15853217/1240557

Comment: @kryger Thank you for correcting me.. Cheers.. I learned something new today.