# Spring Same URL Different Request Parameter

Tags: spring, http-request-parameters

```
public String searchUserById(@RequestParam(value = "fileType", required = true) String fileType) {
    System.out.println(fileType);
    return "downloadexcel";
}

public String searchUserByName(@RequestParam(value = "fileType", required = true) String fileType, @RequestParam(value = "batchNo", required = true) String batchNo) {
    System.out.println(fileType + " ----------- " + batchNo);
    return "downloadexcel";
}
```

This kind of URL Patterns i need  I found some relevant Questions but i am getting 400 bad request when hitting the url

1.`http://localhost:8080/apna-shopee/download.htm?fileType=mani`
2.`http://localhost:8080/apna-shopee/download.htm?fileType=mani&batchNo=1001`

Didn't find the correct solution.

Comment: Hi, I think you could manage both requests in the same method in your controller if you set required = false for batchNo parameter.
In this case you should check the value of batchNo in your controller (if its null, it wasn't in the URL)

Comment: That is what i am doing now., see the below question comment. but i am learning spring with this application so please help me out., if you know about parameter passing.,Thanks

Comment: Which solution would you like to use? One method which can handle both cases, or two different methods for the two cases?
Another question: did you add the @RequestMapping annotation to your methods?

Comment: In class level I have added @RequestMapping

Answer (score 0):

visit following link this may help you to solve your issue
[create two method for same url pattern with different arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853035/create-two-method-for-same-url-pattern-with-different-arguments)

You can also do this based on condition. just make simple method with two parameters and based on second parameter value you can perform appropriate action. i.e if second parameter value is null that means request done using only single parameter

Comment: But in my case i ll get 1 parameter in 1st case & two parameters in second case In both the cases i have one common parameter

Comment: Exactly i don't have idea about how to manage if there is common parameter in request. i will update it as soon as found

Comment: OK. Thank you for your response @Krupesk Kotecha

Comment: But  I Have to change entire logic in the both cases there is lots of difference in these two

Comment: ya that might happen. will let you know if i found any other solution

Comment: For Now I am doing in the same way. But to learn spring i have to learn how to make in correct way. Now  i am creating two private methods in my controller and calling those accordingly based on condition