# Extending or Overriding a REST API without disturbing client

Tags: java, spring-rest, spring-batch-admin

I am working with [Spring Batch Admin API](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/spring-xd-dirt/src/main/java/org/springframework/xd/dirt/rest/BatchJobInstancesController.java) to have Admin Screens working for my batch Jobs.

I am using [this client](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin-samples)

In above code of `BatchJobInstancesController` , UI is very slow for End Point - `instancesForJob(...)`. Its slow because of too much unnecessary data not needed by UI being added.

So I am trying to write a new service or end point that replaces/overrides only that end point or service without least disturbing angular client.

How to approach it?

Service method [SimpleJobService.getJobExecutionsForJobInstance](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin/blob/master/spring-batch-admin-manager/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/admin/service/SimpleJobService.java) needs to be overridden to change the logic.

How can I disable only that end point and plug in new code?

is it possible for new code to serve at same URL?

I mean this seems a common scenario where you are trying to use somebody else's N number of services but want to tweak only a few services.

**EDIT:** No answer from long time, I will try on lines mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853035/create-two-method-for-same-url-pattern-with-different-arguments)