# Spring boot override function in controller

Tags: java, spring, controller

I want to have one url for two functions. The first without parameters and the second with parameters.

code:

```
@RestController
public class MainController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String search(@RequestParam(value = "search") String... keys) {
        return Arrays.toString(keys);
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String results() {
        return "results!";
    }
}
```

Right now it keeps throwing me an error. is there a solution for it?

Thanks.

Comment: use required=false in @RequestParam and check whether your keys is null or not if it's null then use your results logic otherwise use your first method logic.

and remove the second mapping

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853035/create-two-method-for-same-url-pattern-with-different-arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a `params` parameter to the `@GetMapping`, which will allow the mapping to be limited to requests which include those params

```
@GetMapping(path = "/", params = {"search"})
public String search(@RequestParam("search") String... keys)
```

See the [documentation for @GetMapping#params](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html#params--).