# Create two methods for the same URL pattern with different arguments (with argument and without argument)

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'd like to use one URL mapping `/all` **with request parameters** (`month`, `date`) or **without parameters**.

I've tried to create two methods, one without parameters:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public CommonResponse getAll() {

}
```

And one with parameters:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public CommonResponse getByMonth(@RequestParam int month, @RequestParam(required = false) int year) {

}
```

But i am getting **"Ambiguous mapping found"** `IllegalStateException`. Does Spring have any way to handle this situation?

**Note:-** Please don't suggest this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15853217/9993404) because I have different scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution :)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public CommonResponse getAll(@RequestParam(required = false) Optional<Integer> month, 
                             @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "0") int year) {

    if (month.isPresent()) {
       return getByMonth(month.get, year);
    }

    return getAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two different mappings with same path is impossible. 
But maybe you can do something like this :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public CommonResponse getByMonth(@RequestParam Integer month, @RequestParam(required = false) Integer year) {
        if(month == null && year == null) {
            return getAll();
        } else {
            return getByMonth(month, year);
        }
    }
```

Or you can change one variable to a path variable on your second mapping

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/all/{month}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public CommonResponse getByMonth(@PathVariable("month") Integer month, @RequestParam(required = false) int year) {
    }
```

Comment: This is PathVariable not RequestParam.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create two methods for the same url, you have to make your month param optional, and check in code if the month is present or not.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public CommonResponse getAllOrByMonth(@RequestParam(required = false) Integer month, 
                                      @RequestParam(required = false) Integer year) {
    if (month != null) {
        // Get by month
    } else {
        // Get all
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create two method for the same URL, check  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15853217/9993404)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public CommonResponse getAll() {

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/all", params = {"month", "date"}, method = 
RequestMethod.GET)
public CommonResponse getByMonth(@RequestParam("month") int 
month,@RequestParam("date") int date, @RequestParam(required = false) int year) 
{

}
```