# Configure controller in a way that optional sorters can be enabled/disabled based on the controller's input

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, controller

I am trying to write an endpoint that allows the use of optional sorters in the backend.

For example, I have a sorter that allows me to sort elements in a list - which is what my endpoint's controller returns - based on their creation date.

If the corresponding controller parameter is `true` then the elements are sorted started *from the newest and moving towards the oldest*.

If the corresponding parameter is `false`, then *the opposite*.

This is a Spring Boot project.

***I was wondering if there is a more spring-appropriate way to achieve this?***

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
public class StudentsController{
    @Autowired
    private GradeBook yearlyGrades;

    @GetMapping("/successful")
    public List<Student> getSuccessfulStudents(
        @RequestParam(name = "startDate") Instant startDate,
        @RequestParam(name = "endDate") Instant endDate,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "false", required = false) boolean sortStartingFromHighestGrade,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "false", required = false) boolean sortStartingFromEarliestDate) {


        return this.yearlyGrades.getSuccessfulStudents(startDate, endDate, 
                                                       sortStartingFromHighestGrade, 
                                                       sortStartingFromEarliestDate);
    }
}
```

Depending on the `true/false` value of the last two parameters:

> sortStartingFromHighestGrade
>   sortStartingFromEarliestDate

Different processing happens in the background in the service class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring can come handy in multiple ways here:

1. From the point of view of Spring MVC you don't have to supply all request parameters in separate variables, Instead you can define a class with all these parameters and spring will map them for you:

```
public class Params {
  private Instant startDate;
  private Instant endDate;
  private int page = 0;
  private int size = 10;
  ... constructor/getters/setters ...
}
```

Then in your controller you can do the following, IMHO, looks more clean:

```
@GetMapping
public Page<Student> getSuccessfulStudents(Params params) {
   ...
}
```

As @nazar_art has mentioned, you can use Pageable support of spring data **if you have spring data** Otherwise you'll have to implement it by youself, which is not a big deal anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement sorting with spring with [Pageable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html) support.

You will create a Pageable object for getting the data from DB.

You could use `PagingAndSortingRepository` for Spring Data:

```
public interface StudentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Student, Integer> {
```

And call regular `.findAll(pageable)` with any Sorting option for your entity at the service layer.

And your controller will look something like:

```
@GetMapping
public Page<Student> getSuccessfulStudents(
        @RequestParam(name = "startDate") Instant startDate,
        @RequestParam(name = "endDate") Instant endDate,
        @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "0") int page,
        @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false, defaultValue = "10") int size) {
    return yearlyGrades.getSuccessfulStudents(startDate, endDate,
                 PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by("propertyFromClass")));
}
```

If you don't want to return `Page<Entity>` you could convert it to List at the service layer.

***UPDATE:***

Instead of creating ***Pageable*** object by `PageRequest.of()`, you could pass it directly by URL:

> /successful?page=0&size=10&sort=grade

where `grade` is a field from **Student** class.

or

> /successful?page=0&size=10&sort=grade,ask

All parameters internally recognize by Pageable as following:

```
page - Page number

size - Page Size

sort - sort by (Order by)

direction - ASC / DESC
```

Then your controller should be:

```
@GetMapping("/successful")
public Page<Student> getSuccessfulStudents(
    @RequestParam(name = "startDate") Instant startDate,
    @RequestParam(name = "endDate") Instant endDate,
    Pageable pageable) {
    return yearlyGrades.getSuccessfulStudents(startDate, endDate, pageable);
}
```

Useful references:

- [Spring Data Pagination Sorting](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting)

Answer (score 0):

If processing on the backend is really different, then you can define different endpoints with the same `path` but different `params` field which allows defining additional conditions, see `@GetMapping` annotation docs and example in [create two method for same url pattern with different arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853035/create-two-method-for-same-url-pattern-with-different-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

if you are asking at API level then this is not related to Spring but rather to REST API design and here multiple notations can be used

```
GET ...&sort=+grade and GET ...&sort=-grade
GET ...&sort=grade.asc and GET ...&sort=grade.desc
GET ...&sort=asc(grade) and GET ...&sort=desc(grade)
```

for more params

```
GET ...&sort=+grade&sort=-age
GET ...&sort=+grade,-age
```

for spring part take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.Direction.html
and
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html