# SpringDoc Problem With Methods With Different Query Parameters

Tags: spring-restcontroller, springdoc

I want to do something like [create two method for same url pattern with different arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853035/create-two-method-for-same-url-pattern-with-different-arguments)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchUser", params = "userID")
public String searchUserById(@RequestParam long userID, Model model) {
  // ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/searchUser", params = "userName")
public ModelAndView searchUserByName(@RequestParam String userName) {
  // ...
}
```

Spring supports this and it works fine. SpringDoc does not. It creates a single endpoint with 2 parameters.Is this a known issue?

Comment: Have you found solution to this?  I have same issue with `@GetMapping` methods having same path but different `@RequestParam`

Answer (score 0):

This is supported, but you will have to use swagger `@Operation` to describe **your methods in one path**.

One of the OpenAPI 3 rules.

`Two POST methods for the same path are not allowed – even if they have different parameters (parameters have no effect on uniqueness).`

More details are available on OpenAPI 3 [site](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/).

This has been explained here: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/580

Comment: Nothing to do with POST methods.  Same with @GetMapping

Comment: This honestly sucks. The OAS3 spec is dumb in this regard.